# IOS 5 - UIWebView duplicating requests to Rails server

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails-3, uiwebview, ios5

I have a IOS 5 application that uses a Webview which shows some HTML received from the server.
The HTML has a form and a submit button.
The backend is a RoR 3 server.

When I click the submit button it is sending two duplicate requests to the server. 
If I test the same HTML in a browser it does not send duplicate requests.

Any ideas?  It is inserting two records in the DB. I want a good solution , not an unique index in the DB.

The HTML code of the page is very simple:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="user_questions">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8"     action="http://localhost:3000/questions/actions/sendQuestion" method="get">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://localhost:3000/questions/41/voteup?user_id=10&amp;lesson_id=7&amp;deviceName=iPhone&amp;origin=user">
                    <img alt="Up" src="http://localhost:3000/assets/up.gif" />
                    </a>0
                    <a href="http://localhost:3000/questions/41/votedown?user_id=10&amp;lesson_id=7&amp;deviceName=iPhone&amp;origin=user">
                    <img alt="Down" src="http://localhost:3000/assets/down.gif" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <a href="http://localhost:3000/questions/41?user_id=10&amp;lesson_id=7&amp;deviceName=iPhone&amp;origin=user">Question 1</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input id="userQuestion" name="userQuestion" type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Send" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is generated on the server and sent to the App via REST/Json, then setted to the webview using [webView loadHTMLString:htmlQuestions baseURL: nil];

Thanks

Comment: @meccan Just posted some code...